# ffmpeg; copy stream 1 encode stream 2

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that first audio stream is aac and the second is DTS. I want to copy the first one but re-encode the second one to aac.
The code I use usually is:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -stats -i "Movie.mkv" -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=20 -map 0 -c:a copy "MovieOut.mkv"
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i "Movie.mkv" -map 0 -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=20 -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 aac "MovieOut.mkv"
```